# xx should xxx be in place

Tags: syntactic-analysis

"The PM is seeking legally binding changes to the backstop - the plan to avoid the return of Irish border checks **should** no EU-UK trade deal **be in place**."
I don't understand the grammatical structure.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The first line is the Prime Ministers aim: this is to make changes to the backstop agreement.

Most of the sentence is a definition of **the backstop-**.
  So, **the backstop** is the plan to avoid **XXXX** if there is no **EU-UK** trade deal.

> She wants to change **the backstop-** which is the plan to avoid **the return of Irish border checks** should no EU-UK trade deal be in place.

When "if" is removed from a conditional clause, there is inversion.

> Read as: "...the plan, if no EU-UK trade deal should be in place"

In very formal English 'were to,' 'should,' and 'might' are still used:

> Read as: "...the plan, if no EU-UK trade deal is in place".

Comment: I completed the whole question. Can you complete your answer, please?  I'm still a little confused.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like that you are not clearly understood in the clause below.

> should no EU-UK trade deal be in place

The original form (before inversion) is "if no EU-UK trade deal should be in place".

We can move should to position it in front of the clause, condtioning that we remove the 'if':

Should no EU-UK trade deal be in place. ('no' implies 'not any' and the clasue is in a negative form)

> If he should not leave now, I would also stay here.

> Should he not leave now, I would also stay here.